# Deleting a zip file using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want delete a zip file using codeigniter

This is my controller file:

```
public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('ag_angel1');
        $this->db->where('angel1_id',$id);
        $this->db->join('ag_file','ag_file.file_id = ag_angel1.angel1_id','left');
        $ag=$this->db->get()->result();
        foreach($ag as $g){

            $path=realpath('uploaded/angel1/'.$g->file_name);

              if (file_exists($path)) {
              $this->load->helper('file');
                delete_files($path) or die('failed deleting: ' . $path);
              }else{
              $this->load->helper('file');
              unlike($path);
              }

        }
```

Code in model:

```
function delete($id)
    {
        if(!$id==null){

            $this->db->where('angel1_id',$id);
            if($this->db->delete('ag_angel1'))
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->delete is used to delete data from a databse to delete a file use unlink

```
<?php unlink(server_path_to_your_file);?>
```

use this code in your model instead

```
function delete($id)
    {
        if(!$id==null){

        $this->db->where('angel1_id',$id);
        if(unlink('path_to_your_file'))
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```